# Forward parameters in the specific order (using link_to helper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I want to forward parameters from one view to the another one, and this is what I managed to do. But I want to pass those parameters in the specific order. On first request, after I send the form, I get the params in the order that I want. For example:

`http://www.example.com/someurl?project_id=1&start_date=2016-01-10&end_date=2016-01-20`

Then, after I have those params in the view, I generate a link with link_to helper, in this kind of a way:

```
= link_to "link text", some_specific_path(some_id, {"project_id"=>"1", "start_date"=>"2016-01-10", "end_date"=>"2016-01-20"})
```

But then, the link will be generated as:

`http://www.example.com/someurl?end_date=2016-01-20project_id=1&start_date=2016-01-10`

So, the problem is - when I send a form, parameters get added to the url in the order of how they appear in the form. But, when you generate a link with link_to helper and path helper, then parameters are always added in the alphabetical order, no matter how they actually appear.

Comment: I don't no why this matters, but you could try to generate the url like so:
    some_specific_path(some_id) + "?param1=value1&..." The only thing you have to do is to generate the query string from your hash.

Comment: Ok, this can work out, even though it's a bit ugly. I just want to keep the urls consistent and in some meaningful order (doesn't make sense for end_date to appear before start_date).

Comment: Well, you rather have more work to do, put some ugly code, just to have a pretty URL? This won't matter to the system. I wouldn't give myself the trouble...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid ugly code and looking for some meaningful solution, but I'm probably just shooting in the dark :)

Comment: Why do you need your query string parameters sorted?

Comment: As I mentioned above, it's just because of the aesthetic and UX reasons - wanted to keep the same order while navigation through content/tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Rails bug https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1146

also, consider send params between request in sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my solution for you, but it's realy **urly**:

```
hash = {"project_id"=>"1", "start_date"=>"2016-01-10", "end_date"=>"2016-01-20"}
query_string = hash.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")
link_to "link text", some_specific_path(some_id) + "?" + query_string
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good idea to define a helper here:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_with_sorted_params(text, path, _params)
    prepared_params = _params.map { |k,v| "#{k}=#{v}" }.join("&")
    prepared_link = "#{path}?#{prepared_params}"

    link_to text, prepared_link
  end
end
```

Call it

```
=link_to_with_sorted_params("hi", users_path, {"user" => 1, "res" => 2})
#=> <a href="/users?user=1&amp;res=2">hi</a>
```